# Is there a way to prevent ma req.params from chaning when calling res.redirect or res.writeHead methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to redirect user to a specific URL after I do the check with the received parameter from req.params.url.

However, i have that async method for checking if some url exists in redis storage, and my res.redirect is executed before the check is finished, so my req.params.url has been changed and wrong data is sent for checking.

I've tried to create an immutable object but didn't work.

My check method should stay async

```
async function keyExists(key) {
  let client = redis.createClient();
  client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Error ' + err);
  });
  const res = await client.get(key.toString());
  return res;
}

async get(req, res) {
        try {
            let url = req.params.url;
            let urlCheck = req.params.url;
            console.log(req);
            if (url === '' || isNullOrUndefined(url)) {
                throw new Error('There was something wrong w with reading the data');
            }
            const exists = await redisService.keyExists(urlCheck);
            if (exists) {
                // res.status(302).send('Redirecting');
                console.log('Redirect');
                res.status(302).redirect(exists);
                res.end();
            } else {
                res.status(404).send('URL does not exists');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).send(error.message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please (really) read over ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) instead of just pasting in something from an email or a forum post. Stackoverflow uses [well documented markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), please make sure to use that.

Comment: Is your `keyExists` method truly asynchronous? Does it return a Promise?

Comment: @WillAlexander it does return a Promise yes

Comment: I don't see how the request changing would change the URL that is sent. Is it a string that you're sending (as `req.params.url`) or an Object?

Comment: @WillAlexander It is just a string.
When I send it to the keyExists method, it continues further with the execution.
Then it goes to the else block down there, after that, my res.params.url is overwritten.

Comment: I don't see how it can be overwritten, as it is passed by value. Have you tried throwing everything into `then` blocks to make sure the logic is sound?